# Match and replace character in column in R

Tags: r, replace, string-matching, grepl

I have been working on the following issue and cannot seem to solve it. Please give me your suggestions on how to solve it.

Let's say I have the following data frame.

```
NAICS 2017  NAICS 2012_1    NAICS 2012_2    NAICS 2012_3    NAICS 2012_4
2100    2111    0   0   0
9110    9119    5114    0   0
1113    5676    4875    2186    1153
6220    6225    1293    0   0
1115    3234    2163    0   0
7110    7873    0   0   0
1100    2679    8153    2114    1145
```

I want to essentially replace the NAICS 2017 column with the matching 2-digit NAICS if it exists within the other 4 NAICS columns.

So the code would determine if there is a 2 digit match (2100 matches 2111) then replace the 2 digit code with the four digit code. (2110 becomes 2111).

Here is how the final code would look.

```
NAICS 2017  NAICS 2012_1    NAICS 2012_2    NAICS 2012_3    NAICS 2012_4
2111    2111    0   0   0
9119    9119    5114    0   0
1153    5676    4875    2186    1153
6225    6225    1293    0   0
1115    3234    2163    0   0
7110    7873    0   0   0
1145    2679    8153    2114    1145
```

Optional Addition: Only change the NAICS code if the NAICS 2017 column is a 2 or 3 digit code (i.e. 2100 or 2110).

Could this be done with a grepl or gsub code?

If you would like a full data set please don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Your input and expected output look identical to me.  Typo somewhere?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - it took me a couple of looks too - the first column is the one that changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, the `update` column is the result:

```r
library(dplyr)

it <- data.table::fread(
"    NAICS_2017 NAICS 2012_1    NAICS 2012_2    NAICS 2012_3    NAICS 2012_4
    2100    2111    0   0   0
    9110    9119    5114    0   0
    1113    5676    4875    2186    1153
    6220    6225    1293    0   0
    1115    3234    2163    0   0
    7110    7873    0   0   0
    1100    2679    8153    2114    1145"
)

it <- mutate_all(it, as.character)

matchit <- function(x){
  tmp <- x[-1]
  mypattern = paste0("^",stringr::str_sub(x[[1]],1,2),".*$")
  hit <- tmp[which(grepl(mypattern, tmp))]

  return(ifelse(length(hit), hit[[1]], x[[1]]))
}

it$update <- apply(it, 1, matchit)
it
#>   NAICS_2017 NAICS 2012_1 NAICS 2012_2 NAICS 2012_3 NAICS 2012_4 update
#> 1       2100         2111            0            0            0   2111
#> 2       9110         9119         5114            0            0   9119
#> 3       1113         5676         4875         2186         1153   1153
#> 4       6220         6225         1293            0            0   6225
#> 5       1115         3234         2163            0            0   1115
#> 6       7110         7873            0            0            0   7110
#> 7       1100         2679         8153         2114         1145   1145
```

Explanation:
The function returns the first match of the pattern in a row(except the 1st element), if not, it returns the 1st element,
Then we can update the data.frame by applying it to each row.

Comment: Thank you very much this answer worked perfectly! If I wanted to only change the number in NAICS_2017 if the value ended in a zero (i.e. 1100 or 1110), how would I go about adding that to the function?

Comment: add a filter then, such as `it <- it %>% dplyr::filter(grepl(".*0$", NAICS_2017))`